# Difficulty dealing with an equation involving a single-variable function and a multi-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am self-studying with a book named "Calculus Ideas and Applications" by Himonas and Howard. Here is the problem (edited as it contains  reference to a previous problem):

"Suppose the ends of the string are clamped to the x-axis at the points 0 and $L$, and the string is raised to a position given by $y = f(x)$, for some twice-differentiable function $f(x)$. It can be shown that after the string is released, its position at any time $t$ will satisfy $y = u(x, t)$, where $u(x, t)$ is a solution of $\frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2} = c^2\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}$ for a suitable constant $c$. Show that the function $u$ defined by $$u(x, t) = \frac12(f(x+ct) + f(x-ct))$$ satisfies $\frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2} = c^2\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}$ and also the initial conditions $u(x, 0) = f(x)$ and $\frac{∂u}{∂t}(x, 0) = 0.$"

I worked on this for a long time. The problem is that I cannot differentiate that unknown function $f$, which I substituted with various polynomial and exponential functions, and I do arrive at the conclusion. However, that does not prove it, as I am only working with examples and I need to generalize it, i.e. to prove it for any function $f$. But I cannot think of a way to differentiate an unknown function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can differentiate $u(x,t)$ using the chain rule.  For instance,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\left(f'(x+ct)\cdot c+f'(x-ct)\cdot (-c)\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2}\left(f'(x+ct)\cdot 1 + f'(x-ct)\cdot 1\right).
\end{equation}
The multiplication (by $\pm c$ in the first equation and by 1 in the second equation) is the chain rule: we're multiplying by the relevant derivative of the argument of $f$.  Can you now compute the desired second derivatives?

Comment: Now I see. Thank you. Just why did I not see it?